# Authors fields in domino DDS REST api

Tags: api, rest, lotus-domino, author, reader

I am building a Javascript Web application with a Domino back end, using the Domino DDS REST api to do POST, PUT, and GET operations against the database.  I want to use Authors and Readers fields in documents to control which users can see which documents and to give users with Author access in the ACL  the ability to edit documents they have created.  When doing a POST of a new document (implemented by the save() method of a new Backbone model) is there a way to designate one or more fields as Readers or Authors?
Doing a GET on an existing document returns a JSON object with an attribute named '@authors' containing the names and roles in the Authors fields.  Is this attribute read/write?
Can I populate @authors with the desired values before doing a POST to have these values control author access?
My colleague says the Domino REST api makes no provision for setting Authors and Readers fields, and that this functionality can only be done through Java servlets.  Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Domino DDS REST API, but from what I gather it is doubtfull that when POSTing a document, you get to chose the type of the fields. I suspect they all end up as text.

What you could do however is to link the action of your form to a Domino agent which, using the backend [Java or LotusScript API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESITEM_CLASS_JAVA.html), will be able to control precisely the final shape of your document, hereby allowing you to fully utilize the powerfull security model of Domino.

Nevertheless, keep in mind that at some point, your users will have to authenticate against the Domino Directory. Depending where your users originally log in, you may need to talk to your Domino administrator to sort out a Single Sing-On scheme linked to your *other* directory.

Alternatively, you could take advantage of the fact that Domino is also a web server and an application server : you can build your HTML form in there, starting with a  [Domino form](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT__FORMS.html) (simple) or an xPage (a bit more complex).
You may want to [have a look here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Redbooks%3A+Building+Domino+Web+Applications+using+Domino+8.5.1#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=redbooks).

Some would say that you could even build your whole application in Domino, as using it as a mere back-end data repository is akin to using a Rolls-Royce to ferry potatoes, but I suppose that you and your organization have good reasons to do so.

Finally you could also completely ditch Domino and use another nosql database like MongoDB, but that would only displace your access control problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can post data back to Domino and nominate a form to use. If you use the 'computewithform=true' parameter and the form design includes the authors/reader fields you need, this will set the field flags correctly and automatically.